# Solve $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N \sin^4 (5n)}{N}$

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N \sin^4 (5n)}{N}$$

This is an Olympiad problem from India. I tried solving it by trying to manipulate such that n/N is x and then integrate it along with reducing the sin^4 to cos using double angle formulae twice. But I got stuck when a term to be integrated resembled cosx/x which I was unable to integrate by the methods I know. But judging the kind of problems this exam asks, I think there is a more elegant approach that does not require knowledge of integrating the aforementioned.

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx9gq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $5n$ mod $\pi$. As $n$ increases, you get a dense covering of $[0,\pi]$. So one way to express the following integral as a Riemann sum is $$\int_0^{\pi}\sin^4(x)\,dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sin^4(5n)\Delta x_n$$ You could argue the sampling is uniformly dense such that it is OK to take $\Delta x_n=\frac{\pi}{N}$. Then you conclude
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N \sin^4 (5n)}{N}
&=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \sin^4 (5n)}{N}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^4(x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\left(1-\cos(2x)\right)^2\,dx\\
&=\text{... more elementary integration ...}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac32\,dx\\
&=\frac38
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why can one argue that the sampling is uniformly dense?

Comment: how did you convert sin (5n) to sinx  ? if dx is pi/N , then how is x =5n.Also the dense covering would be periodic while n varies from 0 to pi .Plz correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @AtharvKapila As far as $\sin(x)$ is concerned, $\{5,10,15,20,\ldots\}$ is the same as $\{5-\pi,10-3\pi,15-4\pi,20-6\pi,\ldots\}$. These are sample points for a Riemann integral over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: .Here how is it correct to assume all sub intervals of equal length of π/n ?                                PS: I studied a bit of Reimann integrals right after you mentioned it so pardon me for bothering you for elementary doubts

Comment: @AtharvKapila There is certainly something to be wary of. One approach is to center a Riemann sum rectangle of width $\pi/N$ at each sample point. This will (a) leave you with overlapping rectangles and (b) not entirely cover $[0,\pi]$. The question is if in the limit these things don't matter. I'm afraid I'm not interested in writing up a proof about this. If you feel that a different answer is more convincing, I would go with that answer instead. However, I suspect that the intent of the Olympiad problem authors was this approach: realizing how that awkward sum is the same as an integral.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}&\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^N\sin^4(5k)=\\=&\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^N\left(\frac{e^{5ik}-e^{-5ik}}{2i}\right)^4=\frac1{16N}\sum_{k=0}^Ne^{20ik}-4e^{10ik}+6-4e^{-10ik}+e^{-20ik}=\\=&\frac1{16N}\left(\frac{e^{20i(N+1)}-1}{e^{20i}-1}+\frac{e^{-20i(N+1)}-1}{e^{-20i}-1}-4\frac{e^{4i(N+1)}-1}{e^{4i}-1}-4\frac{e^{-4i(N+1)}-1}{e^{-4i}-1}+6(N+1)\right)=\\=&\frac38+\frac1{16N}\left(\frac{e^{20i(N+1)}-1}{e^{20i}-1}+\frac{e^{-20i(N+1)}-1}{e^{-20i}-1}-4\frac{e^{4i(N+1)}-1}{e^{4i}-1}-4\frac{e^{-4i(N+1)}-1}{e^{-4i}-1}+1\right)\end{align}

And here it depends how familiar are with limits of complex-valued functions. I would say that the quantity between parenthesis is bounded in $N$ (for instance, its absolute value is bounded by $1+\frac{8}{(\cos20-1)^2+\sin^220}+\frac{32}{(\cos 4-1)^2+\sin^24}$) and therefore the limit as $N\to \infty$ is $\frac38$. Otherwise you calculate the $a+bi$ form of that quantity (which will have $b=0$) and then draw the same conclusion with the resulting expression in $\sin(N+1)$ and $\cos(N+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

[@Gae.S](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/239203/gae-s) has answered before me.

Here's an approach using trigonometry

$\begin{align}\sin^4(5n) = \left(\dfrac{1-\cos(10n)}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1-2\cos(10n)+\cos^2(10n)}{4} = \dfrac{1-2\cos(10n)+\frac{1+\cos(20n)}{2}}{4}=\dfrac{3-4\cos(10n)+\cos(20n)}{8}\end{align}$

Now $\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{n=0}^N\frac38 = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac38\left(\frac{N+1}{N}\right)=\frac38\end{align}$

Using the formula,

> $$\sum_{n=0}^N\cos(kn) = \frac{\sin((N+1)\frac k2)}{\sin\frac k2}\cos\frac {Nk}2$$

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{\cos(20n)-4\cos(10n)}{8} \\&= \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sin(10N+10)}{8\sin(10)}\frac{\cos(10N)}N-\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sin(5N+5)\cos(5N)}{2\sin(5)}\frac{\cos(5N)}N\\
&=0 ~~(\text{As}, \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cos x}x = 0)\end{align}$$

So the final result is $\frac38$